# Hebrew file names as ???.txt

Tags: linux, putty, winscp

on Linux I see Hebrew file names as ???.txt using putty . on WinScp it looks fine.
is it a putty issue or Linux (shell) issue ?
when I run locale I'm getting in the LANG  :
LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: This Question not related to stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to set the charset to UTF-8 or a charset that supports Hebrew.

For more details, see: http://thegreyblog.blogspot.co.il/2009/08/configuring-putty-to-use-utf-8.html or https://serverfault.com/questions/475925/how-to-fix-putty-showing-garbled-characters